# how to set onItemclick.It shows error for c<arrayList>?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set OnItemClick on my button, but once I pass the parameter it shows error for my holder and the last parameter "c" that is my ArrayList
here - onItemClickListener.onItemClick(songHolder.btnAction,v,i,c"THIS ARRAY LIST SHOWS ERROR WHAT DO I HAVE TO PASS HERE");

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SongHolder songHolder, final int i) {
   final  Songinfo c = _songs.get(i);
    songHolder.songName.setText(c.SongName);
    songHolder.ArtistName.setText(c.artistName);
    songHolder.btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(onItemClickListener !=null) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(songHolder.btnAction,v,i,c);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return _songs.size();
}

public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView songName, ArtistName;
    Button btnAction;

    public SongHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        ArtistName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ArtistName);
        btnAction = itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show your onItemClickListener interface class

Comment: that's not an arraylist. It's just a single list item

Comment: @Vivek Mishra _songs is an arrayList

Comment: @SandeepMalik but `c` isn't.

Comment: @Vivek Mishra  you are right budy c is not an array list

Comment: he is passing the wrong variable in onItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

you have to change in your Interface class onItemClick method according to your code ;-

change ArrayList to Songinfo into your Interface according to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this @Ashir,

```
public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView songName, ArtistName;
Button btnAction;

public SongHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
    ArtistName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ArtistName);
    btnAction = itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Do your code here

            }
        });

}
}
```